# Android -obfuscationdictionary option and retrace

Tags: android, proguard

I use `-obfuscationdictionary` option to **Proguard** with a `dictionary.txt`. When I retrace the error stack trace, it cannot be worked out. I read the official **Proguard** manual, but it doesn't help. What can I do with this problem?

Comment: Can you post how do you retrace error stack? BTW You should not use dictionary.txt for it